# In terms of lowest computational complexity, how to create a new pandas column which increments by a certain number based on another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have this column of numbers, sorted by value

```
import pandas as pd 
  
# initialize list of lists 
data = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 6, 6]
  
# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['First']) 
df.head(19)

First
0   1
1   1
2   1
3   1
4   2
5   2
6   3
7   3
8   3
9   3
10  3
11  3
12  4
13  4
14  5
15  6
16  6
17  6
```

I would like to add a column, that increments by a certain number down the column if the column value is in a particular row is the same as the previous value. When going down the rows, and encountering a new row value in 'First', the increments restarts at 1 (or zero).

Here is an example dataframe of the result I am looking for.

```
    First   Second
0   1   1
1   1   2
2   1   3
3   1   4
4   2   1
5   2   2
6   3   1
7   3   2
8   3   3
9   3   4
10  3   5
11  3   6
12  4   1
13  4   2
14  5   1
15  6   1
16  6   2
17  6   3
```

What have tried so far

I tried extracting the column to a list, and using a loop to create the new column, which then can be appended to dataframe

```
colimnList = df['First'].tolist()
newColumn = []
old = -1
toAdd = 1 
for item in colimnList:
    if item == old:
        toAdd+=1
        newColumn.append(toAdd)
    else:
        toAdd=1
        newColumn.append(toAdd)
        old = item
newColumn

[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 3]
```

Is there a method that is  more efficient computationally, or at least more programmatically elegant? Possibly done in pure pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas has a "groupby" operation that does almost exactly what you need, called [cumcount](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html).  It starts each group from zero, whereas you want to start from one, so just add one and you'll get the result you want:

```
df.groupby('First').cumcount() + 1
```